# printing db values to html django

Tags: django, python-3.x

can anyone help?

I want to print some counts from the DB (total records where the complete field = true and another when it equals false.

What have I done wrong in the below?

Thanks

VIEWS

```
def task_count(request):
    completetasks = Todo.objects.filter(complete=True).count()
    incompletetasks = Todo.objects.filter(complete=False).count()
    return render(request, 'counts.html')
```

URLS

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.todo, name='index'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.create_task, name='create'),
    url(r'^counts/$', views.task_count, name='counts'),
```

COUNTS.HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<br><br><br>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<div class="container">
        {% filter upper %}
<h3>Notes for task</h3>
{% endfilter %}

</div>
{{ completetasks }}

{% else %}
<h2><a href="/login">Login</a></h2>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your views file change like this

```
def task_count(request):
    completetasks = Todo.objects.filter(complete=True).count()
    incompletetasks = Todo.objects.filter(complete=False).count()
    context = {
        'completetasks': completetasks,
        'incompletetasks': incompletetasks
    }
    return render(request, 'counts.html', context)
```

Then in `counts.html`

```
{{ completetasks }}
{{ incompletetasks }}
```